# How do you get syck to compile with php5.2.x

Tags: php5

What are the steps needed to compile in support for [syck](http://www.whytheluckystiff.net/syck/) into php 5.2.x on a 64 bit centos 5.3 system?

I haven't seen this another good FAQ on this, so I figured I would drop both the question and answer here since it took me a good while to figure out. If anyone appreciates, please upvote both Q & A so I know to keep posting things like this here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking and answering your own question.  But it would be better if you actually try to phrase it so the 'question' is actually a question.  (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23456/)

Comment: Thx, i just hadn't posted the answer yet, so it seemed kind of strange in the interim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes: This was a 64 bit centos 5.3 box

So first I had to download source for both syck and php.
I extracted them to ~/syck and ~/php5 respectively .

if you just try to configure php5 further adding in syck, you will see there is no configure option to add it in:

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# ./configure --help |grep syck
[z@abc php-5.2.6]#
```

next, I set up some compiling options

export CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"
this gives me level 3 optimization and a processor independent compile.

then build syck

```
[z@abc syck-0.53/ext/php]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/syck
[z@abc syck-0.53/ext/php]# make -j4
[z@abc syck-0.53/ext/php]# make check
[z@abc syck-0.53/ext/php]# make install
```

now I copy the php extension dir for syck over into php's ext area

```
cd {SYCKSRCDIR}
cp -r ext/php ../{PHPSRCDIR}/ext/syck
cd ../{PHPSRCDIR}
```

Then I changedir back over to php (~/php5)

Now that syck is in php's ext dir, i can run buildconf and it will pick it up and put it into the configure options for php5

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]#  ./buildconf --force
```

If you are interested to see what happens, you can run the buildconf without the --force, it won't hurt anything, but will fail to run

Now I get

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# ./configure --help |grep syck
--with-syck=DIR       Include syck support 
[z@abc php-5.2.6]#
```

So php will now let me add syck as a statically compiled module.. w000t!!

Finally:

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' --with-syck=/usr/local/syck
```

Then it's make time!!!

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# make -j4
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# make test
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# make install
```

Done!! woot

To check my work:

```
[z@abc php-5.2.6]# /usr/local/php5/bin/php -m
[PHP Modules]
.
.
.
syck
.
.
.
[z@abc php-5.2.6]#
```

yup php -m sees it as a module!